# Android Custom ListView not displaying the view

Tags: android, android-layout

Am trying to create a custom listview but it cant dispaly am really a newbie and need the help .... Here's the code

```
public class Main_Activity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new MyAdapter(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.textView1,
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories)));

}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);

        ImageView image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView text =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        text.setText(items[position]);

        if(items[position].equals("Life")){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lifeico);
        }

        else if(items[position].equals("Corporate")){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.corpico);
        }

        else if(items[position].equals("umash")){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.umashico);
        }


        return row;
    }
}
```

//then the listview layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//using the compound drawable layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lifeico"
android:drawablePadding="5dp"
android:text="@string/textview"
android:textSize="25sp" >

</TextView>
```

//and the resource list of items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="categories">
    <item name="Life">Individual Life</item>
    <item name="Corporate">Corporate Insurance</item>
    <item name="Umash">Umash Funeral Services</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Is There any error in your logcat? debug your code to find out which line gives you error or checking data step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you really haven't given us enough to go on (like a logcat of errors if available or a log statement not being reached), it could be any number of things.

I'd say that there must be issue with the `View row` xml that you are inflating `View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,`. That could be the incorrect name, but is the entire layout, just the `TextView`? If so, you should (add the imageView &) put it in a `ViewGroup`, like `RelativeLayout`,`LinearLayout` etc. just like your main layout is. But most alarming is probably:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1); <-
    TextView text =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1); <-
```

can you see that you're referencing two different views by the same id? the latest image command might be screwing it up.

Moreover, it's best practices not to do what's unnecessary in `getView` since it is called for each row of the `ListView`. That's what passing things through the constructor are for (items which you seem to have ignored), so that they're only done once. Try it like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new MyAdapter(
        this, 
        R.layout.list_item,  <--
        R.id.textView1,  <------
        R.id.imageView1, <------ make sure these are all correct
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories)));

}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private int resource;
    private int textViewResourceId;
    private int imageViewResourceId;
    private String[] strings;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, 
            int imageViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.imageViewResourceId  = imageViewResourceId;
        this.strings = strings;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

        ImageView image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(imageViewResourceId);
        TextView text =(TextView)row.findViewById(textViewResourceId);

        text.setText(strings[position]);

        if(strings[position].equals("Life")){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lifeico);
        }

        else if(strings[position].equals("Corporate")){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.corpico);
        }

        else if(strings[position].equals("umash")){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.umashico);
        }


        return row;
    }
```

you could have even passed all your constructor parameters straight through if they were all in the same master class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter. Inherit your adapter from BaseAdapter
Two important point:

First: Array adapter gets it's data in an array through it's constructor. so it dose not need to call getStringArray in getView() again. You can use of ArrayAdapter.getItem(index) to get a specified object at a position.

Second: The ConvertView(the second parameter in getView method) is a scaped view that you can use of it for setting data, if it is not null. by this way you do not need to make or inflate a new view and you can use of some view that is released by ListView previously.

Answer (score 0):

You are making an ImageView out of nowhere.

You should be getting a ClassCastException in your logcat. Add a real ImageView (not TextView) to your layout, using an LinearLayout to have both the TextView and ImageView.

You should also recycle your views for performance:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View row = convertView;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
   }
   ....
}
```